# Any way to create an image from pixel settings?

Tags: pixel, pixel-art

Meaning if I were to provide coordinates and a colour for each individual pixel e.g.(7,12, #767963), specify a pixel size for the entire canvas, can I make a picture from it? Which program has this function? Whether to extract these details or reverse-engineer your own custom picture made from pixels?

Comment: Depends on your exact needs, but probably [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) → [Drawing -- IM v6 Examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/)

Comment: I don't think you need any software, except perhaps a text editor. It's possible to code a bitmap image by hand. [See this link](http://magazine.art21.org/2011/09/13/how-to-create-a-bitmap-image-file-by-hand-without-stencils/#.XDYVTc2nyUk)

Comment: The output of a scanner ( or even a fax machine) is a series of colour and brightness levels for every unit (pixel) on the page, following a pre-determined scan line pattern called a raster.